# GetX Get.toNamed() using id parameter returns Route id (0) not found

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, flutter-routes

Creating a flutter GetX persistent BottomNaviagtionBar and struggling with navigate to internal pages inside the tabs view mantaining the bottom bar...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:getx_persistent_bottombar/app/routes/app_pages.dart';

import '../controllers/tab1_controller.dart';

class Tab1View extends GetView<Tab1Controller> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Tab1View'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              'Tab1View is working',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => Get.toNamed(Routes.INTERNAL1),
              child: Text("internal 1"),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => Get.toNamed(Routes.INTERNAL2, id: 0),
              child: Text("internal 2"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Note that internal1 opens on top of all, and internal2, when passing 'id' parameter on Get.toNamed() return error:

```
======== Exception caught by gesture ===============================================================
The following message was thrown while handling a gesture:
Route id (0) not found

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      GetNavigation.global (package:get/get_navigation/src/extension_navigation.dart:1088:9)
#1      GetNavigation.toNamed (package:get/get_navigation/src/extension_navigation.dart:592:12)
#2      Tab1View.build.<anonymous closure> (package:getx_persistent_bottombar/app/modules/tab1/views/tab1_view.dart:27:36)
#3      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:989:21)
#4      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:198:24)
#5      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:608:11)
#6      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:296:5)
#7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:230:7)
#8      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:563:9)
#9      PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:94:12)
#10     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:139:9)
#11     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:539:8)
#12     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:137:18)
#13     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:123:7)
#14     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:439:19)
#15     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:419:22)
#16     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:322:11)
#17     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:374:7)
#18     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:338:5)
#19     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:296:7)
#20     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:279:7)
#24     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:169:10)
#25     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:293:7)
#26     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:88:31)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#46f01
  debugOwner: GestureDetector
  state: possible
  won arena
  finalPosition: Offset(182.2, 186.4)
  finalLocalPosition: Offset(47.7, 23.9)
  button: 1
  sent tap down
====================================================================================================
```

the complete code is at

https://github.com/tva77/getx_persistent_bottombar

So, how to handle internal pages with GetX and mantain the bottom bar?

Comment: Can you please clear what needs to happen when internal2 opens? Do you want to have same behaviour of internal 1? what is id:0?

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the values with constructor. It is much safer.